# Is it possible to edit or expand a linq expression passed as a parameter?

Tags: c#, linq

Pseduocode:

```
var pocos = GetPOCOs(p => !p.IsDeleted);

public List<MyPoco> GetPOCOs(Expression<Func<MyPoco, bool>> exp)
{
    List<MyPoco> pocos = new List<MyPoco>();

    foreach (int i in MyListOfIntegers)
    {
        // this will not compile - but is a similar function possible?
        pocos.AddRange(GetPocos().Where(exp && p => p.PocoId == i));
    }

    return pocos;
}
```

I know there are other ways I could go about this (i.e. just filter the list twice), I'm just curious.

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When I need to manipulate conditions, I just try to use `IQueryable` when possible, and at the very last moment materialize it. I use this when creating reports in my application (adding different filters based on user input.)

```
IQueryable<MyObj> qry = MyDAL.GetObjs();

if (someCond) {
    qry = qry.Where(p => p.SomeCond == someValue);
}

if (someOtherCond) {
    qry = qry.Where(p => someCollection.Contains(p.SomeValue));
}

return qry;
```